# Why is "have given" not correct in "...and ___ him his hard earned success..."?

Tags: word-choice, exam-questions

My question is about this sentence correction exercise:

> The qualities which have supported Tilak and **given** him his hard earned success have been rare in Indian politics.

The only options are

> 1. gave
> 2. have given
> 3. had given
> 4. no improvement

Here instead of given (gave) is used, why is "have given" not correct?

Comment: It's ***given*** because this is an example of "deletion of repeated (and therefore expected / unnecessary) word". It's thus a "reduced" form of *qualities which have supported tilak and **have** given him success*. Perfectly natural in English. Using ***gave*** wouldn't exactly be grammatically "incorrect", but it would be an ugly/awkward mix of tenses, which native speakers would avoid.

Comment: So have given can be used?  Or gave, which is more appropriate?

Comment: Use either *...qualities which **supported** tilak and **gave** him success* or *...qualities which **have supported** tilak and **[have] given** him success*, whichever you prefer. Just don't ***mix*** Perfect and Simple Past forms in such a construction. Arguably the Perfect is more appropriate if you want to connect the assertion to time of speaking - especially the final ***have been rare***, which strongly implies that (Tilak excepted) such qualities both were and are ***still*** rare.

Comment: Actually its a sentence improvement question and only given is highlighted so we have to correct it only          options are  1)gave 2)have given 3)had given 4) no improvement

Comment: @rishabhagarwal - It's very hard to understand what your question is because you don't clearly say "This is from a test, and **given** was highlighted as something we needed change.  The 'correct' answer was '_____'"

Comment: The text as cited is best. Of those alternatives, as I have already explained, ***have given*** is simply the "long" version of the original (it's perfectly acceptable, and I think the test-setter is badly mistaken if he thinks it's meaningful to suggest that "fully-expanded" version is somehow either better ***or*** worse than the "deleted" version as cited). The other two alternatives are either stylistically awful or actually ungrammatical (offhand I'm not sure which, but *don't even think about using them*).

Comment: I've tried to make your question easier to understand rishabh - please feel free to [edit] it if I've added something that isn't correct.

Comment: Frankly, exercises like this are stupid, since any of the three options can work in certain contexts.

Answer (score -2):

It seems that your example comes from a poorly-written set of questions.

[This Mahatma Academy page](http://mahatmaacademy.com/english-language/english-grammar-sbi-pos-upsc-ibps-clerks-rrb-ssc-ias-csat-kpsc/) includes ten questions.   The seventh matches your example.

Of these ten, half are flawed.   Even the page as a whole is flawed, since the directions for the entire set is nonsensically repeated after the heading for the first question.   This gave me reason to wonder who is responsible for this site.   I'm still left wondering.   The [*about* page](http://mahatmaacademy.com/about/) contains WordPress example text, without a hint of the site's purpose or authorship.

Consider the very first question offered:

> **Question No:1**
>    
>   **Directions** In the following questions, a part of the sentence is **bold**. Below are given alternatives to the **bold** part at (1), (2), (3) and (4) which may improve the sentence. Choose the correct alternative.
>   He **told** his tale of woe with tears in his eyes.

At a glance, I naturally assumed that no improvement was needed.   However, that option isn't offered:

> (A) narrated
>   (B) recited
>   (C) was telling
>   (D) narrate

Despite the phrasing of the directions, there are no options provided at (1), (2), (3) or (4).   I can eliminate option (D) as an ungrammatical structure in model sentence.   It fails to employ proper subject/verb agreement.   The rest are grammatically sound.   Since we are given no further context, I see no reason to prefer any of them to the simple "told" of the original model.

The provided answer key considers (A) to be correct.   I can't explain that choice.   Apparently, neither can the site, given how badly the following is formatted and phrased:

> **Explanation:- tell (Verb) :** to give information to somebody by speaking or writing **narrate (Verb) :** to tell a story ; to relate Simple Past Tense ‘narrated’ will be used

This explanation, such as it is, supports leaving the verb alone at least as well as it supports the substitution.

This Mahatma Academy page certainly, and the site as a whole most likely, is too flawed to be of any use.

[EverydayQuiz](https://everydayquiz.blogspot.com/2016/10/english-mix-quiz-set-11.html) also references the model sentence involving Tilak, followed by the same options.   The answer key on that site sensibly lists *(D) No Improvement* as the correct choice.   That, at least, is an answer that I can understand and explain.